# Integrating Google IMA to my application, not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

i've trying to integrate google IMA sdk into my application in order to view a preRoll advertisement, following Google IMA's guide, here's what i did:

```
    - (IMASettings *) createIMASettings {
    IMASettings *settings = [[IMASettings alloc] init];
    settings.ppid = @"IMA_PPID_0";
    settings.language = @"en";
    return settings;
}


- (void)createAdsLoader {
   // self.adsLoader = [[IMAAdsLoader alloc] initWithSettings:[self createIMASettings]];
    self.adsLoader = [[IMAAdsLoader alloc] initWithSettings:[self createIMASettings]];
    self.adsLoader.delegate = self;
    [self requestAds];
}

- (void)requestAds {
    NSString *adTag = @"http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?env=vp&gdfp_req=1&impl=s&output=xml_vast2&iu=/12215557/nawa3em-house-video-preroll&sz=640x360&unviewed_position_start=1&url=http://www.nawa3em.com&correlator=1292013319811";
    IMAAdsRequest *request =
    [[IMAAdsRequest alloc] initWithAdTagUrl:adTag
                             companionSlots:nil
                                userContext:nil];
    [self.adsLoader requestAdsWithRequest:request];
}
- (void)adsLoader:(IMAAdsLoader *)loader adsLoadedWithData:(IMAAdsLoadedData *)adsLoadedData {
    // Loading was successful.
    NSLog(@"Ad loading successful!");
    self.adsManager = adsLoadedData.adsManager;
    self.adsManager.delegate =  self;
    [self.adsManager initializeWithContentPlayhead:nil adsRenderingSettings:nil];
    self.adsManager.adView.frame = self.theTest.bounds;
    [self.theTest addSubview:self.adsManager.adView];
}

- (void)adsLoader:(IMAAdsLoader *)loader failedWithErrorData:(IMAAdLoadingErrorData *)adErrorData {
    // Loading failed, log it.
    NSLog(@"Ad loading error: %@", adErrorData.adError);
}

- (void)adsManager:(IMAAdsManager *)adsManager didReceiveAdEvent:(IMAAdEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Received ad event.");
    // Perform different actions based on the event type.
    if (event.type == kIMAAdEvent_STARTED) {
        NSLog(@"Ad has started.");
    }
}

- (void)adsManager:(IMAAdsManager *)adsManager didReceiveAdError:(IMAAdError *)error {
    // There was an error while playing the ad.
    NSLog(@"Error during ad playback: %@", error);
}

// Optional: receive updates about individual ad progress.
- (void)adDidProgressToTime:(NSTimeInterval)mediaTime totalTime:(NSTimeInterval)totalTime {
    // This can be very noisy log - called 5 times a second.
    NSLog(@"Current ad time: %lf", mediaTime);
}
```

After trying so many ways, i can't get it work!! it always replies the same error in the app Log 
2013-12-02 15:07:09.944 ima[948:907] Error during ad playback: 
2013-12-02 15:07:09.946 ima[948:907] Relayout
2013-12-02 15:07:09.965 ima[948:907] Received ad event.

knowing that the ad tag url am giving is working after trying it in google's sample application, please i need some help folks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that the complete code? If so, you're never telling the ads manager to start the ad.

```
- (void)adsManager:(IMAAdsManager *)adsManager didReceiveAdEvent:(IMAAdEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"AdsManager event (%s).", AdEventNames[event.type]);

    if (!self.isViewLoaded || !self.view.window) {
        [self unloadAdsManager];
        return;
    }

    switch (event.type) {
        case kIMAAdEvent_LOADED:
        [adsManager start];
        break;
    case kIMAAdEvent_STARTED: {
```

...